# Running Azure CosmosDB stored procedures from Azure Portal

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azureportal

On portal.azure.com, when I press "Save and run" on a stored procedure, the window that shows the procedure's code just closes instead of showing results or errors.
If I run it from a server side code, it works properly, so the issue is not with the procedures themselves.

Comment: Pausing the browser, I discovered that the procedure is executed and the result is showed, but the window closes immediately.
Here's is what it does [link](https://cubeupload.com/im/dsWL3K.gif)

Comment: Hi Mohamed, can you see any Network errors when you execute the Stored Procedure? Network / Console errors can be viewed by opening the browser's dev tools.

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta No, there aren't errors in the console.

Comment: Hi Mohamed, is there a chance of getting a glimpse of the Stored Procedure code? I tried to repro it with my own code but it doesn't happen.

Comment: The problem is not related to my procedures, it accurs even with the azure sample procedure https://jsfiddle.net/8mcvhamp/
I also tried with different browsers, but same result.

Comment: Thanks Mohamed, I understand, but I'm working on reproducing it and I'm not able to with the provided sample stored procedure that the Portal generates. Is your collection partitioned?

Comment: No, it's not partitioned